# core location autopause, effects of activity type

Tags: iphone, ios6, location, core-location

Hi does anyone know the effect that using different CLActivity type constants has on the behavior of auto pause? For example, will the location manager resume from a pause more readily if activityType is set to CLActivityTypeAutomotiveNavigation or CLAcitivtyTypeFitness?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The activity type flags affect the internal auto pause logic. For instance `CLActivityTypeFitness` is more likely to pause when the user is stationary with no accelerometer motion and when the user is moving fast with accelerometer motion similar to a vehicle and vice versa for `CLActivityTypeAutomotiveNavigation`. `CLActivityTypeOther` is supposed to be a catch-all setting for everything else. However the exact logic and thresholds are only known to Apple.

As far as I know, the location updates are only resumed if your app becomes active again, there is no auto-resume depending on the user motion. But you can always start region monitoring in your didPause callback to resume tracking again when the user does move.

Comment: Thanks for this. FWIW, I'm getting `pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO` apparently ignored in the iOS 8 GM.

Comment: Do you mean inside the `locationManagerDidPauseLocationUpdates` do `locationManager.startMonitoringForRegion(region)` **OR** you mean do  like `UNLocationNotificationTrigger(region: region, repeats: false)`? Which one?